# Is is possible to create a dictionary having different number of values at different keys?

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary, indexing

suppose, I have some points connected with each other through lines like shown in the picture, each point here is associated with some values, like point `1:(0,1)` and point `12:(35,36,37).` 
[please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6Q1U.jpg)

I wanted to create a dictionary that will hold the information on all these points. like......(shown below)

```
d = { 1:[0,1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,7], 5:[8,9], 6:[10,11], 7:[12,13], 8:[14,15], 9:[16,17,18], 10:[19,20,21], 11:[22,23,24], 12:[25,26,27], 13:[28,29,30],14:[31,32,33],15:[34,35,36],16:[37,38,39]
```

I don't want users to input these values one by one.
as all the numbers are in some sequence, I guess we can create this kind of dictionary without giving user input.

below shown code was my failed attempt to create this kind of dictionary.

**Note**:- Here the term `dict_point` shows the geometrical coordinates of each point in the system.

please also note that the `t` value here is wrong! it can't be `t = 2 * len(dict_point)` as some points have 3 values associated with them.

```
import numpy as np


dict_point =  {1:[0,0], 2:[1,0], 3:[2,0], 4:[3,0], 5:[4,0], 6:[5,0], 7:[6,0],8:[7,0], 9:[0,-5], 10:[1,-5], 11:[2,-5], 12:[3,-5], 13:[4,-5], 14:[5,-5], 15:[6,-5], 16:[7,-5] }


t = 2 * len(dict_point)
k = dict_point.keys()
straight_list = np.arange(0, t)
paired_list= []
paired_list = [(straight_list[i], straight_list[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(straight_list), 2)]

dict_obtained = dict(zip(k, paired_list))


print(dict_obtained)


dict_obtained :-
{1: (0, 1), 2: (2, 3), 3: (4, 5), 4: (6, 7), 5: (8, 9), 6: (10, 11), 7: (12, 13), 8: (14, 15), 9: (16, 17), 10: (18, 19), 11: (20, 21), 12: (22, 23), 13: (24, 25), 14: (26, 27), 15: (28, 29), 16: (30, 31)}
```

How to create this kinda dictionary in python.

```
dict_desired = d = { 1:[0,1], 2:[2,3], 3:[4,5], 4:[6,7], 5:[8,9], 6:[10,11], 7:[12,13], 8:[14,15], 9:[16,17,18], 10:[19,20,21], 11:[22,23,24], 12:[25,26,27], 13:[28,29,30],14:[31,32,33],15:[34,35,36],16:[37,38,39]
```

Comment: What is the logic here? For the key `n` what should the list look like?

Comment: @mozway sir, i just edited the code here.

Comment: The syntax for your variables *n* and *dict_desired* are entirely correct. Dictionary values can be any Python object. Values within a dictionary do not have to be all of the same type. It's unclear why numpy is involved in this question. There's also nothing in your code that suggests the logic behind the construction of *dict_desired*. If you're trying to derive it from *n* then you'll need to explain a little more

Comment: @Lancelot du Lac
 sir, I tried to explain my problem here, I hope it will give a better understanding.

Comment: Just something like `{x: (x*2-2,x*2-1) for x in range(1,9)} | {x: (x*3-1,x*3,x*3+1) for x in range(9,17)}` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you have written should work in python. Here the key-value pairs for your dictionary are Dict{int: List[int]}.

Answer (score 0):

i think below code will solve your doubt.

```
dict ={}
n=5

dict[1]=[0,1]
dict[2]=[2,3]
dict[3]=[4,5,6]
dict[4]=[6,7,8]

print(dict)
```

Comment: yes, but I want to do this in generalized form,  without giving user input. I am able to do this only for 2 pairs of values.

Comment: @jasonstark Please explain exactly what you mean by "generalised form". There is no apparent logic to show how you should get the *desired_dict* from the dictionary *n*

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic of selecting the bounds is unclear, but here is my interpretation:

```
N = 16
shift = N//2
dict_point =  {}
for i in range(N):
    a = 2 if i<shift else 3
    b = a*i+(a-2)*2
    dict_point[i+1] = list(range(b, a+b))
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 1],
 2: [2, 3],
 3: [4, 5],
 4: [6, 7],
 5: [8, 9],
 6: [10, 11],
 7: [12, 13],
 8: [14, 15],
 9: [26, 27, 28],
 10: [29, 30, 31],
 11: [32, 33, 34],
 12: [35, 36, 37],
 13: [38, 39, 40],
 14: [41, 42, 43],
 15: [44, 45, 46],
 16: [47, 48, 49]}
```